# Gmail API with React

Tags: reactjs, api, gmail-api

I try to create app with Gmail API and with React. For authorization I use [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) 
react-google-login

```
   export default class App extends Component {
  service = new Service();

  render() {
    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
      this.service.getMessagesList();
    }
    return (
      <div>
          <GoogleLogin
    clientId="YOUR_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}

  />
```

After authorization I send fetch request to gmail [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and try to get my emails list. But server return me 401. Why? What I did wrong?

My fetch:

```
export default class Service {
_apiBase = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me";
async getResource(url) {
  const res = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, received ${res.status}`);
  }
  const body = await res.json();
  return body;
}

getMessagesList = async () => {
  const list = await this.getResource(`/messages`);
  return list;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means Invalid Credentials. If you're getting this error, then most likely, the credentials you're using is invalid. You might be using a wrong type of credential.

Try going to [console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and checking your credentials again. You may refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) if you are looking for more information regarding implementing authorization.